# Setting default page for asp.net core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently learning asp.net core and I would like to set the login page as the first page the users see when they open the app, but only if they are not logged in yet, otherwise they should see the index page as per usual.

So far I found that I could get what I want by changing the method `Configure` in Startup.cs, specifically the inner method `app.UseMvc`, which looks like this

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I know that if I modify the property "template" to look for the Login controller and action would do the job. But the problem is, the login on my app was created by the framework Identity classes, therefore I can not reference the controller nor the action, because they don`t exist, what I have is a folder containing the files Login.cshtml and Login.cshtml.cs, which were scaffolded by the code-generator. The Login functionality works just fine, but not where I want it to.

So is there any way to reference the Login even if it is not a Action from a controller?

Comment: You do have a login controller, it's just compiled inside a DLL that comes as part of the Identity framework. Have you tried `template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");` for example?

Comment: Do you mean that every action and page needs an authenticated user? Or do you simply want the default route to point to the login screen?

Comment: Why would you send the user to the login page all the time: what if the user has logged in already? You need to decorate your other controllers with `Authorize` attribute and the framework will send the user to the login page if the user is not logged in.

Comment: @DavidG I tried now, it didn't work. And I didn't know about that DDL, so thank you anyway.

Comment: Oh, I was not very clear with the question. I want the Login to be the first page the users see when they open the application, just that, not the default page to be redirected to.

Comment: Just to clarify, even if the user is already logged in, you want them to see the login page?

Comment: @AdamVincent no, if they are not logged in, they get redirected for the login page, otherwise they get redirected for some other page.

Comment: Are you using Controllers/Actions or Razor Pages? As @CodingYoshi stated, it should just be a matter of marking the relevant Controllers/Actions or Razor Pages as requiring authorisation.

Comment: @KirkLarkin only now reading your question i was able to undestand what @CodingYoshi meant, I put the `Authorize` Attribute in my Index Action in Home controller and it automatically sends the user to the login page. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how much this will help , but you can try this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class |
 AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SessionTimeoutFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ISession session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

        if (session.GetString("UserID") == null)
        {
            var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

            controller.TempData.Add("Msg", "Redirection to Login Page, Reasons : Session Timeout or Unauthorized access");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "Controller", "LogIn" },
            { "Action", "Index" }
                });
        }
        else
        {
        //redirect to dashboard or other page as per your need 
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This is a custom filter , you can decorate your Login Controller with this.
Now explanation

- It will check session value , here it is UserID , you can use your
  session keys here ,  If session does not exist than it will redirect to login page
- But if session exist than you can put a else statement to redirect on
  your dashboard screen.